# Rotate a graph created with Sigma Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization, sigma.js

I would like to rotate my graph created with Sigma.js to have a more complete view of the graph, I managed to do it with 'camera'  but only around one axis, I wonder if it is possible to do it around several axis. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A camera only has :

- a coordinate (x,y) position
- an angle (rotation)

Sigma render a graph in 2D, not in 3D, so what you ask is not possible.